# Windows Starting a service returns ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED

Tags: windows, visual-c++, service

I have successfully created a service:

```
hService = CreateService(hSCManager,lpServiceName,lpDisplayName,
                         SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,    
                         SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, 
                         dwStartType,  
                         SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,  
                         lpFilePath,              
                         NULL,                  
                         NULL,                  
                         NULL,                 
                         NULL,                  
                         NULL);
```

But when I try to start the service:

```
hService = OpenService(hSCManager, lpServiceName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);

if (StartService(hService,0,NULL)== NULL){
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
}
```

The error is equal to `ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED`. How does one enable the service? This is not immediately obvious from the Windows API documentation.

Comment: The value of `dwStartType` is not `SERVICE_DISABLED = 0x00000004` A service that cannot be started. Attempts to start the service result in the error code `ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx